# Question on the proof that $f'(x_0)=0$ is a necessary condition that $f(x_0)$ is a maximal element

Tags: real-analysis

The proof first and then below my question:

> Let $f$ be defined on an open interval $I$ around $x_0$. If f has a
>   local extremepoint in $x_0$ and is $f$ differentiable in $x_0$ then
>   $f'(x_0)=0$

Proof

Because $x_0$ is a local extremum there must be a neigbourhood $N$ of $x_0$ where $x_0$ is a global extremepoint for the constraint $f_{|N}$. For $x\in N$ s.t. $x>x_0$ $(*)$ must hold

$$(*)\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\leq 0$$

$x\downarrow x_0$ **implies** $f'(x_0)\leq 0$. Analogously one could show $x\uparrow x_0\Rightarrow f'(x_0)\geq 0$  $\square$

Question

I don't understand the implication, the Information which should be conveyed is that the oppsite cannot be true but how was this verrified before?

Comment: You are asking why the sentence with the bolded "**implies**" is true?

Comment: yes I am referring to the bolded implication

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
We are told that this limit exists. Therefore, it also exists (and has the same value) if we take the limit from above:
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \downarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
By equation $(*)$, $(f(x)-f(x_0))/(x-x_0)\leq 0$ for all $x \in N$ with $x >x_0$. If we let $x \downarrow x_0$, then certainly eventually $x \in N$ and $x>x_0$. Therefore, taking the limit of nonnegative quantities, we get something nonnegative. That is, $f'(x_0)\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in N$ since it is a local maximum, hence $f(x)-f(x_0)\leq0$ for all $x\in N$.  If $x>x_0$ then we have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\leq 0
$$
and similarly if $x<x_0$ we have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\geq 0
$$
Thus $f^\prime(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

See Theorem 2.23 of [these notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf)

You know that the limit on the left handed side of the inequality $(*)$ exists:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}= \lim_{x\downarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(x_0) $$

You also know that the limit on the right handed side of the inequality $(*)$ exists as well:

$$ \lim_{x\downarrow x_0} 0 = 0 $$

So by theorem 2.23:

$$ f'(x_0) \leq 0 $$